# "Drop Zones" with Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there a way to create a "drop zone" like that of [interact.js](https://interactjs.io/) using fabric.js?

I haven't necessarily tried anything. I have my ideas as to how I would try to implement it, but thought I'd ask around and search the web for help, so I don't have to invent something if it's been done. I've searched on Google with no success.

*Note: I am trying to stay away from adding another library, especially if I am only going to use it to accomplish one thing in functionality, so yes, I could just use interact.js, but I'd rather not store or reference another library if at all possible.

---

### Answer:

For those who are looking for a possible solution to this... It could be implemented via isContainedWithinObject(other, absoluteopt, calculateopt) → {Boolean}... I found this after reading the documentation on fabric.js. I would just draw 9 rectangles (top left, top center, top right, middle left, middle center, middle right, bottom left, bottom center, and bottom right), then run the method on the objects where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a classic input method and style it like a dropzone with css. See snippet below.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(400);

document.querySelector("#pdf-upload").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0]
  if (file.type == "image/jpeg" || "image/png") {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var data = event.target.result;
      fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(image) {
        var imageObject = image;
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageObject);
        imageObject.scaleToHeight(300);
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
  $("#canvas").css("visibility", "visible");
  $(".dz").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

```css
.dz-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dz-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-left: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 120px 0 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: dotted 5px black;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-color: rgba(155, 105, 255, 0.2);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.dz-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(155, 105, 255, 0.3);
}

#canvas {
  border: solid 1px black;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dz">
    <div class="dz-text"><b>Drop image here</b></div>
    <input class="dz-button" id="pdf-upload" type="file">
  </div>

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works like a charm, but its not what I am going for. I need it to detect if a fabric element has entered or exited the zone, be it IText, a rectangle, a fabric image, etc. Not to mention, I need 9 of those... One in each corner of the canvas, one on the top, bottom, and sides, respectively, then one big one in the middle. The idea is when an element is put inside of the drop zone that it would get centered... and the boxes need to be dynamic, not a set size, which I should hopefully be able to handle with css, the main problem is element detection and creating the boxes.

Comment: So really the problem with this code is, I need it to detect if a element is inside the container, which is inside the canvas. I figure maybe I could use like a fabric rectangle, and put a border around it, and make the fill white, but then I didn't know how to detect if there was an element inside of the rectangle.